# Python37 and Django 2 TextField not a string?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

We decided to migrate our django 1.10.5 project with python 2.7.15 to a newer version of python and django. Now we are using python 3.7 and django 2. After some problems with our email sending script I found something strange. When sending automated mails we took text from a TextField in the database and inserted it into our Mail.

```
content = content.replace('##ENTRY##', entry.text)
```

The text field of entry is a django models.TextField.
Now with python 37 it doesn't allow me to use it like that. I have to wrap the entry.text into a str() cast. But shouldn't the TextField be a string?

```
content = content.replace('##ENTRY##', str(entry.text))
```

With that it works, but it lets my tummy hurt when doing it like that, since i don't understand why.

Edit:

```
    def send_task_entry_new(entry):
    content = Email.load_email_template('tasks.watcher.info.entry.new')

    content = content.replace('##TAG##', entry.task.get_tag())
    content = content.replace('##ENTRY##', entry.text)
    content = content.replace('##SUBJECT##', entry.task.get_subject())
    subject = entry.task.get_tag() + " " + entry.task.get_subject()

    for watcher in entry.task.taskwatcher_set.all():
        if watcher.user.last_login:
            content = content.replace('##LINK##', settings.BASE_URL + entry.task.get_absolute_url())
        # If User has never logged in (Dummy for external task user)
        else:
            content = content.replace('##LINK##', settings.BASE_URL + reverse('tasks_public', args=[watcher.token]))
        Email.send(watcher.user.email, '', '', subject, content)
```

Entry is an TaskEntry object which gets created as soon as I create a Task. The TaskEntry model looks like this. At least the attributes of a TaskEntry:

```
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
external = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Edit Flow:

Email comes in and get processed:

```
text = get_decoded_email_body(response_part[1])
```

which fires:

```
def get_decoded_email_body(message_body):
msg = email.message_from_bytes(message_body)

if msg.is_multipart():
    # Walk through all parts of this email
    for part in msg.walk():

        # print "%s => %s" % (part.get_content_type(), part.get_content_charset())
        charset = part.get_content_charset()

        #TODO umstellung auf Python3 enfernen und testen
        if part.get_payload(decode=True):

            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                if charset:
                    return str(part.get_payload(decode=True), charset, 'ignore')
                else:
                    return to_unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True))

            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                if charset:
                    return str(part.get_payload(decode=True), charset, 'ignore')
                else:
                    return to_unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True))

    return "Email has no text/plain or text/html part"
else:
    return to_unicode(msg.get_payload(decode=True))
```

After that we got our text extracted and create a now task:

```
user = User.objects.get_or_create(email=sender)[0]
task = Task.objects.create(subject=subject, creator=user)
task.create_entry(text, user) #Here it crashes
Email.send_task_operators_new_task(task, text, sender)
```

Now into the models.py and we go into create_entry:

```
    def create_entry(self, text, creator):
    entry = TaskEntry()
    entry.text = text
    entry.task = self
    entry.creator = creator
    entry.save()

    if creator:
        TaskWatcher.objects.get_or_create(task=self, user=creator)
```

Next step is the .save() method:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.pk == None:
        created = True
    else:
        created = False
    super(TaskEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if created:
        # If this entry is the first one inform creator and owner if given
        if self.task.taskentry_set.all().count() == 1:
            Email.send_task_created_to_creator(self.task)

            # If a owner has been given how is not the creator
            if self.task.owner and self.task.owner != self.task.creator:
                Email.send_task_created_to_owner(self.task)

        # This is not the first entry, so inform all watcher about the new entry
        if self.task.taskentry_set.all().count() > 1:
            Email.send_task_entry_new(self)
```

Now it executes the Email.send_task_entry_new(self) and throws the replace() error.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't allow you? What error do you get?

Comment: The error i get is:
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not bytes

So if i cast the entry.text into an str() it works. But I wonder why it worked with python 27 and django 1.10.5. I did not change anything in the models and the text field is still a TextField.

Comment: I think you need to show more context. Where is `content` and `entry` coming from exactly? Are they directly from models?

Comment: I added some more informations.

Comment: Thanks but I think we need to see the code that defines `entry` in the first place before passing it to this function. It seems that it is a newly-instantiated object, rather than one loaded from the db. Can you show the full flow?

Comment: I added the flow. Maybe the problem is how i extract the payload out of the email body, since I handle it as bytes. Maybe I should just convert it to str() before inserting it into the db

Comment: Well the important point here is that you instantiate an Entry and then use it directly. So none of Django's sanitation or unicode conversion comes into play - you just get back what you put in, which as you say is bytes. The data that is saved in the db is correctly handled, and if you were working with an object that you was retrieved from the db again it would be unicode. So, yes, in this case calling `str()` at the point when you assign it to the `text` attribute would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman I found the issue. Since I take the payload from the mail as bytes and never convert it into a string, it is saved as bytes into the db. As soon as I request the data from the db it is bytes and I have to convert them into string as I need it.